# Display data from web service (Js, Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've been trying to display some data from a web service with no luck
I tried this

```
ngOnInit(){
    //console.log(this._productoService.getDeudas());
    this._productoService.getDeudas().subscribe(
      result =>{
        console.log(result.Cuotas);       
      }
    );
  }
}
```

and i got this error

```
 Property 'Cuotas' does not exist on type 'Response'.
```

this is the data i got in the console

[image]

any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: Does this work: `result => { result ['Cuotas']; }` ?

Comment: @Zze Awesome It works!!! thanks dude, didn't realize it was an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response` is an object and therefore you can use...

```
result => { result ['Cuotas']; }
```

> ... the [`result ['Cuotas']`] field access stands out because you use bracket notation to access the results field. If you tried to write [`result.Cuotas`], **TypeScript would correctly complain that the Object coming back from HTTP does not have a results property.** That's because while HttpClient parsed the JSON response into an Object, **it doesn't know what shape that object is**.

https://angular.io/guide/http